Powershell creating up to 50k xml files ends up in memory leak
I have to loop through a csv file which contains up to 58k lines. Each line has 60 semicolon delimited values.
For each line I have to create one xml file. My script is doing what I expect it should do, but it tooks 20 hours to create 39k files and it runs very slow because it consumes all of the system memory.
Overall have 10 csv files with between 30k and 90k lines. For each of this lines I have to create a single xml file.
How can i avoid this memory consumptions, is there a better way to accomplish this?
I am reading the csv data with Import-csv, looping for each ID in file
This is my code:
function createxmlfromcsvcharge{
$csv = Import-csv $conf_YearFiles$conf_File -Delimiter ";" 
    
foreach($ChargingID in $CSV){

    $ID = $ChargingID.ChargingID
    
    #file name 
    $FileName = "MIS_Record_2013_"+$ID+".xml"
    
    # Creating a simple XML document
    $xmlDocument = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
    
    $dec = ($xmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", $null))
    $root = $xmlDocument.DocumentElement
    $xmlDocument.InsertBefore($dec,$root)
            
    # Adding a root element
    $rootElement = $xmlDocument.CreateElement("ChargingRecord")
    $xmlDocument.AppendChild($rootElement)
    
    # create <ChargingID> container node
    $xmluser = $xmlDocument.CreateElement('Charge')
    $rootElement.AppendChild($xmluser)
    
    # add each property from csv entry to <ChargingID>
    Foreach ($property in $csv[0].psobject.Properties.name) {
        # create a property node
        $xmlproperty = $xmlDocument.CreateElement($property)
        $text = $xmlDocument.CreateTextNode($ChargingID.$property)      
        $xmlproperty.AppendChild($text)
        # add to current <ChargingID> node
        $xmluser.AppendChild($xmlproperty)
    }
    
    $xmlDocument.Save('m:\temp\2013\'+$FileName)
}

}
The code is exactly generating what i am expecting.
Any help or hints is really appreciated. Thank you.

Change $xmlDocument.InsertBefore(...) to [void]$xmlDocument.InsertBefore(...), then do the same thing with all the AppendChild(...) calls - otherwise these method(s) output a reference to the inserted/appended node, causing PowerShell to collect it as output, in turn preventing garbage collection of the xml document instances from previous iterations

Hi Mathias, thanks a lot for this hint, this works perfect! !

Happy to hear! I've added a proper answer below :)

As hinted in the comments, the building memory pressure is causes by the way the XmlDocument API behaves!
When you call InsertNode(...), or AppendChild(...), the inserted/appended node instance is returned.
If you don't actively discard this return value, PowerShell's runtime processor is going to collect them as output. Since the node instances references the owning document, the garbage collector is thus prevented from cleaning up the documents you created during previous loop iterations until the whole method returns and the caller discards the references.
The solution is to discard the return values at the call site - I prefer casting the method invocation expression to [void], but you could pipe to Out-Null or assign to $null for the same effect:
[void]$xmlDocument.InsertBefore($dec, $root)
# or
$null = $xmlDocument.InsertBefore($dec, $root)
# or 
$xmlDocument.InsertBefore($dec, $root) |Out-Null

Repeat for any calls to AppendChild() (and any other method call that returns a node reference) and the garbage collector should be free to do its job :)

It takes a lot of time and memory because it's managing the full weight of the file and relative object.
Just piping Import-Csv to Foreach-Object should improve things:
$DestinationDirectory = 'm:\temp\2013\' 

Import-Csv $conf_YearFiles$conf_File -Delimiter ';' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $ID = $PSItem.ChargingID
        
        #file name 
        $FileName = Join-Path -Path $DestinationDirectory -ChildPath "MIS_Record_2013_${ID}.xml"
        
        # Creating a simple XML document
        $xmlDocument = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        
        $dec = ($xmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration('1.0', 'UTF-8', $null))
        $root = $xmlDocument.DocumentElement
        $xmlDocument.InsertBefore($dec, $root)
                
        # Adding a root element
        $rootElement = $xmlDocument.CreateElement('ChargingRecord')
        $xmlDocument.AppendChild($rootElement)
        
        # create <ChargingID> container node
        $xmluser = $xmlDocument.CreateElement('Charge')
        $rootElement.AppendChild($xmluser)
        
        # add each property from csv entry to <ChargingID>
        Foreach ($property in $PSItem.psobject.Properties.name) {
            # create a property node
            $xmlproperty = $xmlDocument.CreateElement($property)
            $text = $xmlDocument.CreateTextNode($PSItem.$property)      
            $xmlproperty.AppendChild($text)
            # add to current <ChargingID> node
            $xmluser.AppendChild($xmlproperty)
        }
        
        $xmlDocument.Save( $FileName)
    }

